# Does formobject.Dispose() release memory allocations of forms internal datatables?

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory, memory-management, dispose

In my .Net program there is a new form which consist a data-grid data source is set by a datable.

Does formobject.Dispose() at calling point release memory allocations of internal data tables?

or else do i need call data table.Dispose() at form closing?

Comment: Disposing a form will only dispose a DataTable that you dropped as a component on the form with the designer.  Not disposing a DT that you created in your own code is not a problem, DataTable doesn't implement IDisposable itself and has no disposable members.  But .NET programmers usually fret about this anyway so you can dispose your DTs in your OnFormClosed() override.

Comment: Yes now i'm Dispose datables is closing event. 
Is it fine to call every time  GC.Collect() at form closing event??
calling GC.Collect() every time will cause problems for other objects in memory?

Answer (score -1):

On calling Dispose on any class would just clean up memory related to that class or any parent class, if the called method is of a child class. However, no sort of aggregate relationship is considered here.

Hence, if you need to clear memory related to any such aggregate/composite classes, you need to do it explicitly

Comment: `Dispose()` usually doesn't clean up memory, it cleans up unmanaged resources like files or handles.

Comment: Calling `Dispose` never frees any managed memory. Memory is only released by the garbage collector.